# CPU usage of python goes to 0 in windows 10

Tags: python, windows, pygame

I'm working with a tutorial for a flappy birds neat AI game and I tried to run what I have so far, but when my *pygame* window starts it only works for a second and then it freezes. I checked the task manager and it looks like at the begining of the loop it's getting about **36%** of CPU, but after that it goes down to **0%**. Is there a way to prioritize the python task so it gets continuous CPU?

Here's the code im trying to run.

```
import pygame
import neat
import time
import os
import random

WIN_WIDTH = 500
WIN_HEIGHT = 800

BIRD_IMGS = [
    pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird1.png"))),
    pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird2.png"))),
    pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bird3.png")))
]
PIPE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "pipe.png")))
BG_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "bg.png")))
BASE_IMG = pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs", "base.png")))

class Bird:
    IMGS = BIRD_IMGS
    MAX_ROTATION = 25
    ROT_VEL = 20
    ANIMATION_TIME = 5

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.tilt = 0
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.vel = 0
        self.height = self.y
        self.img_count = 0
        self.img = self.IMGS[0]
    
    def jump(self):
        self.vel = -10.5
        self.tick_count = 0
        self.height = self.y

    def move(self):
        self.tick_count += 1
        
        d = self.vel*self.tick_count + 1.5*self.tick_count**2
        
        if d >= 16:
            d = 16
        
        if d < 0:
            d -= 2

        self.y = self.y + d
        if d < 0 or self.y < self.height + 50:
            if self.tilt < self.MAX_ROTATION:
                self.tilt = self.MAX_ROTATION
        else:
            if self.tilt > -90:
                self.tilt -= self.ROT_VEL


    def draw(self, win):
        self.img_count += 1
        if self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*2:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*3:
            self.img = self.IMGS[2]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
        elif self.img_count < self.ANIMATION_TIME*4+1:
            self.img = self.IMGS[0]
            self.img_count = 0

        if self.tilt <= -80:
            self.img = self.IMGS[1]
            self.img_count = self.ANIMATION_TIME*2

        rotated_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.img, self.tilt)
        new_rect = rotated_image.get_rect(center=self.img.get_rect(topleft=(self.x, self.y)).center)
        win.blit(rotated_image, new_rect.topleft)

    def get_mask(self):
        return pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)


def draw_window(win, bird):
    win.blit(BG_IMG, (0,0))
    bird.draw(win)    
    pygame.display.update()

def main():
    bird = Bird(200,200)
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
            bird.move()
            draw_window(win, bird)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
            

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I execute it using `python main.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You have to move the bird and update the game in the application loop rather than the event loop. The event loop is only executed when an event occurs, but the application loop is executed in each frame.

```py
def main():
    bird = Bird(200,200)
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT))
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while run:
        clock.tick(30)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
      
        # INDENTATION    

        #<--|
        bird.move()
        draw_window(win, bird)
    
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```